# Access .json file data in a Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like below

```
class CreateService extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      serviceToUSe: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.hostname == 'hostzeal') {
      this.setState({ serviceToUSe: require('../public/service/hostzeal.com.json') })
    } else {
      this.setState({ serviceToUSe: require('../public/service/default.json') })
    }
  }

  pickService() {
    console.log(this.state.serviceToUSe); // I am getting empty array here.
  }
}
```

My `default.json` file is like below

```
[
  {
    "service": {
      "wordpress": {
        "name": "Wordpress",
      }
    },
    "hosting": {
      "public": [
        "testHosting"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But I am getting empty array.

Comment: are you sure require path is correct? did you try to console log it first?

Comment: where is you render call ? i am doesn't see any calling method of `pickService`

Comment: Check if the if/else statements meets the condition by console.logging stuff

Comment: render method is missing, when do you call PickService() ?

Comment: in my VSCode, throws an error in your json file cause you have a comma after "name": "Wordpress", ---> ODD

Comment: use Import method , import ANYName from '../public/service/hostzeal.com.json'

Comment: Thanks @WaleedNasir. But I need conditional import. How can I do that ?

Comment: You should import them both, then just refer to the one you need.

Comment: Here's a sandbox of it working with hooks: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-thunder-8hxhe